# How to create folder base on users input using cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, directory, cakephp-3.0

`$user= $this->Users->newEntity();`

I want to create a folder for every registered user

example if new user input   **michael**

how to achieve this and will create a directory  `/img/users/michael/`

```
$dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.$user->username);

$path_data = $dir->create($dir);
```

> Error: Cannot use object of type Cake\Filesystem\Folder as array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create directory **PATH** will in in `create()` method

```
$dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.$user->username);
$path_data = $dir->create($dir);
```

should be

```
$dir = new Folder();
$path_data = $dir->create(WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.$user->username);
```

Details [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/file-folder.html#Cake%5CFilesystem%5CFolder::create)

### Update

There is a directory separator missing. it should like

```
$dir = new Folder();
$path_data = $dir->create(WWW_ROOT.'img'.DS.'users'.DS.$user->username);
```

Thanks @ndm

Comment: A note regarding sanitizing the user supplied value would be good. While the OP may have measures implemented that prevent problematic characters being stored/set, it is never a good idea to create such pitfalls, not least because they may be copied by other people. Also there's a directory separator missing after `users`

Comment: still cant create for me

Comment: Im planning to do it uploading files? Scenario when I Upload images or files, it will go to his own directory /img/users/michael/1.jpg OR /img/users/michael/2.pdf,, My function in uploading files is already working . @tarikul05